# Ionic Local Notification Show All

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, local

i would like to push some notifications to my app users twice a day.

the code that i write basically from the ionic documentation, but when i try it on my real device, the notification always showing at the time where the last id is set.

this is my code:

```js
this.localNotifications.schedule([{
   id: 1,
   text: 'Time to get your morning rewards!',
   at: new Date(new Date().setHours(7)),
   every:'day'
  },{
   id: 2,
   text: 'Time to get your morning rewards!',
   at:new Date(new Date().setHours(16)),
   every:'day'
}]);
```

sorry for my very very bad english, i hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into timezone issues. Try this:

```
let date1 = new Date();
date1.setHours(7);
date1.setMinutes(0);
date1.setSeconds(0);

let date2 = new Date();
date2.setHours(16);
date2.setMinutes(0);
date2.setSeconds(0);

this.localNotifications.schedule([{
   id: 1,
   text: 'Time to get your morning rewards!',
   at: date1,
   every:'day'
  },{
   id: 2,
   text: 'Time to get your morning rewards!',
   at:date2,
   every:'day'
}]);
```